# how to use $_SESSION variable in cakephp 2.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using a java script plug-ins to upload multiple images. Fro that I have use a server side script with is with the plug-ins. In that php file I have $_SESSION variable to assign a value in session. But when I am trying to access that session in my controller's method. I have store my javascript file and its corresponding php file in webroot. Is there any way to get session from webroot into controller.

Comment: manual says `$green = $this->Session->read('Person.eyeColor');` is how you read sessions.

Comment: I have tried with this also.

Comment: I think you might have to go to straight PHP on this one... as you might not have direct access to the CakePHP Session Component from your javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

In your php file in webroot, where you have `session_start();`, try changing it to the following:

```
session_name('CAKEPHP'); 
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

SharkofMirkwood's answer worked for me.

```
session_name('CAKEPHP'); 
session_start(); 
print_r($_SESSION);
```

After this you can access session variable using cake's method

ie

```
$this->Session->read('session_name');
```

Comment: Why would you do that?... The above answers are the correct ones.

Comment: @mark The question isn't how to access the session in CakePHP - it's how to access _the same_ session as a standalone php file that's in the webroot. Note also that "the above" depends on how you are sorting answers - there are 3 possibilities, I just changed the order of two of them :P

Comment: Good point. The initial question didn't quite point out the difference between inside and outside the cake app. But then this answer seems correct after all.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to define public variable

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

After that you can use

```
$this->Session->read();
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to write session variable first you need to do is include session component in your controller like :

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

Then write your session variable like:

```
$this->Session->write('variable name', 'your session value');
```

To get this session variable write

```
$this->Session->read('variable name');
```

To delete that particular session variable write

```
$this->Session->delete('variable name');
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Controller please allow the Session component, if you want to use the session component throughout your application then include in the App Controller.

Once you have done this you can access any session data by using the following method.

```
$sessionData = $this->Session->read();
debug($sessionData);
```

If you want to write to the session the you can use the following line.

```
$sessionWrite = $this->Session->write('Site.name', 'My Site Name');
```

The documentation and other functions you can use can be found here.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html